# How to use methods defined in one js file to the other js file in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is, I have a js file having a functionality of opening a tab-bar on clicking. I want the same feature of opening a tab-bar to be used in the other js file as well without adding the methods and functionalities again in that js file. How could this be done?

I have used the method openPane() in this js file,  it shows the error that I haven't defined the openPane(). In order to define I have to include all the other related methods, libraries to this all well, which is not the best way. What would be the recommended way of using entire functionality without defining in the particular file.

This is the file where the adding tab is being defined https://jsfiddle.net/6719phr3/1/

So I want to add a tabbar on clicking Cumulative Data Rate in the below give code.

```
import React, { useState,useCallback } from "react";
import {Card,CardGroup,Badge} from 'react-bootstrap';
 
const Health_status = (props) => {
 return (
<CardGroup>
  <Card className="cards">
    
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>Cluster-1 [ID]</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
      
      </Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
    
      <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className ="sub-cards-rec">
      <Card.Header>Recording Unit [ID]</Card.Header>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>[ID]</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
          <h6 onClick{()=>openPane()}><Badge pill bg="primary" >Cumulative Data Rate:{}</Badge></h6>
          
        {css ? (<h6 onClick={toggle2}><Badge pill bg="success" >Cumulative Sensor Status:{}</Badge></h6>)
          :(<h6 onClick={toggle2}><Badge pill bg="danger" >Cumulative Sensor Status:{}</Badge></h6>)
          }
        </Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
      </Card><br />
      <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className ="sub-cards-ana">
      <Card.Header>Analysis Unit [ID]</Card.Header>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>[ID]</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
        <h6><Badge pill bg="warning" >Instance-Number:{}</Badge></h6>
        </Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
      </Card><br />
  </Card>
  </CardGroup>

  }
  export default Health_status;
```

Comment: Please provide some code to make it clear

Comment: please share some code to explain better what is your problem

Comment: I have added the code, do check.

Answer (score 0):

You can export multiple modules

Export example : Tableloop.js

```
 export function Health_status(prop){return (<div></div>)};
 export  const hari = 123;
```

Import Example : App.js

```
import {Health_status,hari} from "./../Tableloop";
```

Simple.

Comment: I could'nt export the function were it says 'Only one default export allowed per module'.

Comment: How can I import those methods and adding tab into the code I have given?

Comment: just remove default and import as object